# Excel array function for checking monthly values

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I have an array equation to tell me the number of unique values in a column (D) based on whether the date field in another column (B) is in a particular month.

My equation is:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($B$2:$B$63)=10,(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(D2:D63)>0,MATCH(D2:D63,D2:D63,0),""), IF(LEN(D2:D63)>0,MATCH(D2:D63,D2:D63,0),""))>0,1))),0)
```

This works great for October and when I change the 10 value to be another number it works for all months except january. So you can see if I have done a copying error here is the cell relating to January:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($B$2:$B$63)=1,(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(D2:D63)>0,MATCH(D2:D63,D2:D63,0),""), IF(LEN(D2:D63)>0,MATCH(D2:D63,D2:D63,0),""))>0,1))),0)
```

This always returns "N/A"

Any ideas why?

Comment: Obviously when I see the equations in excel I have done Ctrl + Shift + Enter and they have { } around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your construction.

Firstly, the array you are using for the *bins_array* parameter, which is derived from your MATCH construction combined with an IF statement, is forcing FREQUENCY to return an array containing *less than* 62 elements.

When this array is then compared with the initial IF clause, i.e. IF(MONTH($B$2:$B$63)=1, which *does* contain 62 elements, you have an issue, and, where possible, the way in which Excel resolves a comparison between two arrays of differing sizes is to artificially increase the smaller of the two so that it is of a dimension equal to that of the larger.

Of course, in doing this, it fills in the missing values with #N/As (what else could it do?). Hence your result.

In any case, repetition of the MATCH construction is not necessary for the *bins_array* parameter, and forces unnecessary extra calculation. As such, I am always surprised to see how many sources still recommend this set-up.

Finally, any IF clauses should appear *within* the FREQUENCY construction, not *without*.

Overall:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(D2:D63)>0,IF(MONTH($B$2:$B$63)=1,MATCH(D2:D63,D2:D63,0))),ROW(D2:D63)-MIN(ROW(D2:D63))+1),1))
```

is what you should be using.

Regards

Comment: Sure. It's not impossible that it could work, just unlikely. And you're welcome!